# Doctrine 2: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias

Tags: doctrine-orm

*Rather than an actual question, this is a sticky note for myself, that may help others. There are many other similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17878237/759866), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28937655/759866), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34513052/759866), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27502691/759866), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36119781/759866), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35685190/759866), but none of them seems to offer this solution.*

---

I have the following entities:

```php
class Order
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer")
     */
    private Customer $customer;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $amount;
}

class Customer
{
    // ...
}
```

`Order` has a unidirectional, many-to-one relationship with `Customer`. I want to get every customer, along with the total amount of his orders, so I run the following DQL query:

```
SELECT c, SUM(o.amount)
FROM Model\Order o
JOIN o.customer c
GROUP BY c
```

But I get the following error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
> [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT c, SUM(o.amount)': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a known Doctrine limitation.

The solution is to explicitly `SELECT` the entity you want to retrieve (`Customer`) and manually join the other entity (`Order`) from there, using a `WITH` condition:

```
SELECT c, SUM(o.amount)
FROM Model\Customer c
JOIN Model\Order o WITH o.customer = c
GROUP BY c
```